# 2 fair dice (six-sided) are rolled, probability of getting a sum of 7

Tags: probability

Two fair dice are rolled, 
E1 is the event in which first die comes up 4. So P(E1) = 6/36.

E2 is the event in which sum of two dice(regardless of what the first die is) is 6.
E3 is when sum  of two is 7.

So , P(E2) = 5/36 since we have in E2 {(1,5),(5,1), (2,4) , (4,2), (3,3)}
Now what I want to know is:

i)Probability of the event that sum is 6 when first die shows up 4 , should it be P(E1/E2) or P(E1 ∩ E2)? If I use the independent even formula here: i.e P(E1 ∩ E2) = P(E1) * P(E2) , it doesn't satisfy the given answer 1/6.

ii)Probability of the event that sum is 7 when first die shows up 4. 
Now, here if I use P(E1 ∩ E3) = P(E1) * P(E3) , it satisfies the answer.

So I know that (i) is a dependent event, but **why isn't (ii) dependent too?**

Comment: i) should be $P(E1|E2)$ since you are *given* that first die is 4. And it is 1/6 since given first die is 4, the probability of getting a sum equals the probability of the second die being a 2.

Comment: in ii) you could say that the "independentness" of the events is a coincidence of sorts; it only happens with sum of 7. If you think about it, a sum of 7 is equally likely no matter what the first die showed: there's always one unique other number for the second die that will make a 7. That is not true for other sums: if I want a sum of 4, then the probability of that happening depends very much on what the first die shows

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ii) it doesn't matter what the first die is, since whatever it is, there is always exactly one number that the second die is that will get a sum of $7$

This is *not* true for i), since if the first die is a $6$, then the sum can never become $6$

Answer (score 0):

The event of the throwing of two different dice are independent. But as E2 and E3 deals with sum they are no doubt dependent events with E1

Now coming to your inference in (ii)

E1 and E3 are dependent but both of them have probability 1/6 and that's the only reason for the consequence P(E1|E3) =P(E3|E1) =P(E1) =P(E3)